# use java code instead of XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

in my app i cant use XML layout for some reason now i need to create a layout which its XML code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/adlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ir.adad.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    token="fhsfxfhdghghrgfggh" />

</LinearLayout>
```

now i need to create a java code which its the same as this XML code! is there any way?how i can do this?
i:ir.adad.adview is a ad services and i put its liberally in my app.

Comment: use ViewGroup.addView method

Comment: if you can't use xml layout, then you're doing something wrong

Comment: @AlexanderZhak what's wrong in creating Views in java code?

Comment: @pskink sorry but could you explain more?

Comment: use parentView.addView(childView)

Comment: what do you mean `for some reason`? Look at the Logcat, and debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you a bit.

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    int adlayout = 12345;   //if you need id of layout somewhere else  
                           //View.generateViewId();Can be used if minSDK= 17 
    layout.setId(adlayout);

    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 48;
    params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    //Below code is used if you need height in dp.
    //int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, <HEIGHT>, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    ir.adad.AdView adView = new ir.adad.AdView(this);
    int adViewId = 123456;//Should not be dublicate.
    adView.setId(adViewId);
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramView = adView.getLayoutParams();
    paramView.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    paramView.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    layout.addView(adView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know that ad service library I can't help you with its constructor and creation but this should give you something to start working on.

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,48);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    ir.adad.AdView adview = new ir.adad.AdView();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams adviewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adview.setLayoutParams(params);
    adview.setToken("asdasdas");
    layout.addView(adview);
```